# Rest call error from React.js to node backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frontend, backend

the code below performs a rest call from a react.js frontend a backend node.js but when I execute the rest call I see on the backend **Error: Illegal argument undefined**, to remedy this I tried to make a rest call in postman and everything works correctly where is the error?

**Frontend React.js:**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import server from "../../../config/config";
import qs from 'qs';

 restlogin(email,password){ 
   
    const data = { 'Email': email,'Password': password };
     const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
        data: qs.stringify(data),
        url: "http://172.16.53.248:8989/login"
    }
      axios(options);
  }
```

**Backend Node.js**

```
app.post("/login", async function(request, response) {

    var ret = false;
    try {
        //var data = request.body;
        var data = request.body;
        console.log("\n Email: "+data.Email+"\n Password: "+data.Password);

        ret = await UserController.Login(
            data.Email,
            data.Password
        );
    } catch (err) {
        ManageError.SendError("Errore in login: " + err);
        ret = false;
    }
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    response.send(
        JSON.stringify({
            return: ret
        })
    );
});
```

Comment: What show you the console log?

Comment: @YoandryCollazo  Error: Illegal argument undefined

Comment: Which line in back-end throws that error?

Comment: this : ret = await UserController.Login(
            data.Email,
            data.Password
        );

Comment: Could you print "data"?

Comment: this is print of data: [object Object]

Comment: Are you using a bodyParser in your backend? If you're using Express.js, you can simply add app.use(express.json());

Answer (score 1):

Frontend React.js:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import server from "../../../config/config";
import qs from 'qs';


 restlogin(email,password){ 



const data = { 'Email': email,'Password': password };
 const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    url: "http://172.16.53.248:8989/login"
}
  axios(options);


 }
```

---

Backend Node.js

```
  app.post("/login", async function(request, response) {

var ret = false;
try {
    var data = JSON.parse(request.body);
    console.log("\n Email: "+data.Email+"\n Password: "+data.Password);

    ret = await UserController.Login(
        data.Email,
        data.Password
    );
} catch (err) {
    ManageError.SendError("Errore in login: " + err);
    ret = false;
}
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
response.send(
    JSON.stringify({
        return: ret
    })
);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of problems here.

You're passing to the data property the following "qs.stringify(data)" which is a string and the result is something like this: **Email=test%40pmail.com&Password=my%20passwd**

Said that, request.body in you backend is an empty object {} and you will never get these values with this implementation

The reason why with Postman client works is ( I think ) you're passing a JSON object in the body of that your request, but in your React app you're passing a string.

Check is the 'qs.stringify' method is what you really want to use for your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented json-parser on your backend? If not, you need to implement json-parser on backend to receive request which contain JSON body.